# T-Mobile Samsung Galaxy S7 edge Wifi calling with different dialer app

Tags: 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, t-mobile

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge with 7.0 Nougat. I have the google dialer ported and installed to my phone. Since my phone is T-Mobile, I have wifi calling. If i use this 3rd party dialer app, will I still be able to use Wifi-Calling?

Answer (score 0):

Through experimentation, I found out that any dialer app can use wifi-calling because wifi calling is built into the baseband chip's code.